# Hamiltonian circuit 

Tags: big-o

what is the Big-o complexity of finding a Hamiltonian circuit in a given order Markov chain using DFS?

Comment: This seems suspiciously like a homework problem...

Comment: @JK, Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you tell us what your thought process has been on this problem so far?

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation gives the upper bound i.e. the worse case running time. For a Hamiltonian cycle it can be said to be O(n^n)